# TypeScript Default Value for property

Tags: angular, typescript

I have defined an Interface in TypeScript like below:

```
export interface User {
    id?: number;
    name?: string;
    logoUrl?: File;   
    emailUserName?: string;
    emailPassword?: string;
}
```

With User, I bind it to Angular html input. If I enter anything in the input, the User Object will contains the value, But, If I do not enter, the property like name will be undefine. How could I get empty value for name if I do not enter string for name.
Update

```
<div *ngIf="hero">
<h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2>
<div>
<label>id: </label>{{hero.id}}</div>
<div>
<label>name: </label>
<input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name" />
<input [(ngModel)]="hero.location" placeholder="location" />
</div>
<button (click)="goBack()">Back</button>
</div> 
//model
    export class Hero {
    private _location:string="test";
    constructor(){
    console.log(this._location);
    this.location=this._location;
    }
    public id: number;
    public name: string;
    public location:string;
    } 

goBack(): void {
console.log(this.hero);
// this.hero=new Hero();
// console.log(this.hero);
//this.location.back();
}
}
```

goBack will output hero without location property if I do not enter any value for it in input.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have a class for `User` instead of an interface, and in the getter do something like:

```
class User {
    private _name: string;
    ...

    get name() {
        return this._name || "";
    }
}
```

or even assign an empty string to `this._name` in the constructor.

If you prefer to use an interface you can have a function that does that:

```
function normalizeUser(user: User) {
    return Object.assign({ name: "" }, user);
}
```

---

#### Edit

Yes, here's how to set the default value in the ctor:

```
class User {
    private static DEFAULT_NAME = "";

    public name: string;
    ...

    constructor() {
        this.name = User.DEFAULT_NAME;
    }
}
```

As for the `get name()` part, it's an accessor, so if you use it then:

```
let a = new User();
console.log(a.name);
```

[More on accessors](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#accessors).

Comment: Could I set a default value in class `constructor`? For your User class, I am not sure how to use "get name()".

Comment: Check my revised answer

Comment: Thanks, with a click event to run above code, it will the run the `constructor`, and the default value will be set. But for a model binding in Angular, it will not work. I have updated my post with updated code.

Answer (score 4):

Also you can use this shorthand:

```
class User {
  constructor(public id: number = -1,
    public name: string = '',
    public logoUrl: File = 'defaultLogo.png' ,
    public emailUserName: string = ''
    public emailPassword: string = '') {}
}
```

Comment: It seems it did not work, in `constructor`, we could not use '?', and even I remove this '?', the result is undefined

Comment: sorry, thats true! giving an default value implies '?', so any field with default value is optional. sorry i corrected the code!

Comment: I assume your code works when I try something like "let u=new User()", but it may not work when binding with Angular. Please check more information in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Cant you do?

```
this.user.name?this.user.name:"";
```

Comment: Normally, we pass model from component to service, I am afraid this is not a good solution for checking every property whether they are undefined.

Comment: i do not think if there any other solution for checking each property

Comment: I'd go with `this.user.name || ""` instead

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16348972)

Comment: @CinCout why do you say so

Comment: Sounds more like you are yourself not sure about the answer and want the user to try whatever you suggested. @Sajeetharan

Comment: I didn't. I am no expert in the technology in discussion as well. As a reviewer, your solution sounds more like a suggestion, and hence, better suited to be a comment instead.

Comment: when you review , don't just read the answer  , relate with the question also don't flag it if it looks simple :)

Comment: When I say "it sounds more like..", I am referring to the text you used along with your 'simple' coding solution. I did not flag just because the answer was simple.